# как создать такой элемент в html и css

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как создать такой элемент в html и css без картинок

Comment: http://www.cssarrowplease.com попробуйте поиграйтесь тут и думаю поймете)

Comment: там кажется не возможно использовать такой градиент (спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать `clip-path`, если не нужна поддержка `IE` и раннего `Edge`

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.banner-arrow{
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 290px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, lightblue);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 25px) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - 25px) 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-arrow">
  <div class="banner=arrow__text">Грабительские тарифы</div>
</div>
```